# How to (re)scale the x-axis to fit certain points in the graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale, axis

I want to rescale my (qualitative) x-axis so the two peaks (visible in the graph) correlate to their actual values (i. e. 500 keV and 1274 MeV).
How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_from_file(filename):
    return np.loadtxt(filename)

data = list(read_from_file("calibration.txt"))

print(data.index(max(data[:2000])))#x value 500kev
print(data.index(max(data[2000:])))#x value 1274

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = range(len(data))
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.xlim(0, 5000)
plt.ylim(0, 7000)
plt.title("$^{22}$Na Spectrum")
plt.xlabel("Energy")
plt.ylabel("Amount of Photons")
plt.grid()
ax.annotate("500 keV", xy = (1450, 6541), xytext = (1600, 6500))
ax.annotate("1274 MeV", xy = (3500, 950), xytext = (3700, 1100))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `Number of photons` or `photon count`. Pretty sure `amount of photons` is ungrammatical. Just an FYI.

Comment: Also, looking around, I'm pretty sure you mean `0.500MeV` and `1.274MeV` OR `500keV` and `1274keV`, not `500keV` and `1274MeV`.

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `numpy`, you can find the index of the two spikes (i.e. no need to convert the data to a list) using `argmax`.

Then, you can scale the x values using:

```
xnew = val1 + (x - max1) / (max2 - max1) * (val2 - val1)
```

where `val1` and `val2` are the values of your peaks, and `max1` and `max2` are the indices of those peaks.

Here's a bit of code that should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fake some data approximately in your range. You can ignore this bit!
# Random numbers for noise
data = 1000. + np.random.rand(5000) * 100.
x = np.arange(len(data))
# Add the first spike
mu1, sd1 = 1450., 300.
pdf1 = (1./(sd1*2.*np.pi) * np.exp(-(x - mu1)**2 / sd1**2)) * 1e7
data += pdf1
# Add the second spike
mu2, sd2 = 3500., 200.
pdf2 = (1./(sd2*2.*np.pi) * np.exp(-(x - mu2)**2 / sd2**2)) * 1e6
data += pdf2
# End of fake data generation

# Find the index of the first maximum (using your '2000' cutoff)
cutoff = 2000
max1 = float(np.argmax(data[:cutoff]))
# Find the index of the second cutoff
max2 = float(np.argmax(data[cutoff:]) + cutoff)

# The actual values of the two spikes
val1, val2 = 500., 1274

# Scale the xvalues
xnew = val1 + (x - max1) / (max2 - max1) * (val2 - val1)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(xnew, data)
ax.set_ylim(0, 7000)
ax.set_title("$^{22}$Na Spectrum")
ax.set_xlabel("Energy")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Photons")
ax.grid()

# Add some lines at the actual spikes to check scaling worked
ax.axvline(val1)
ax.axvline(val2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Funny you should ask this question. I am currently trying to push an example into MatPlotLib that shows exactly how to do this. You can view the recipe here: https://github.com/madphysicist/matplotlib/blob/7b05223c85741120019b81e1248c20f9bc090c61/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick_transform_formatter.py

You do not need the entire code in the example (or the tick formatter that uses it) but the mapping function will help you create the scaled x-array (also, use `np.argmax` instead of `index(max(...))`:

```
ind500 = np.argmaxmax(data[:2000]))
ind1274 = np.argmax(data[2000:])) + 2000
x_scaled = (x - ind500) * (1274 - 500) / (ind1274 - ind500) + 500
```

You can use `x_scaled` to plot as usual:

```
plt.plot(x_scaled, data)
...
```

Combining it all together (and making a couple of tweaks to use OO API instead of pyplot):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("calibration.txt") # Don't convert this back to a list

ind500 = np.argmaxmax(data[:2000]))
ind1274 = np.argmax(data[2000:])) + 2000
x = (np.arange(len(data)) - ind500) * (1274 - 500) / (ind1274 - ind500) + 500

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, data)
plt.title("$^{22}$Na Spectrum")
plt.xlabel("Energy")
plt.ylabel("Photons Counts")
plt.grid()
ax.annotate("500 keV", xy = (500, data[ind500]), xytext = (550, data[ind500] + 100))
ax.annotate("1274 keV", xy = (1274, data[ind1274]), xytext = (1324, data[ind1274] + 100))
plt.show()
```

The example I linked to would allow you to display the x-axis in entirely different units without actually modifying your x-array.

Comment: @Philipp. It is customary to select one of the answers that worked by clicking on the check mark under the answer score. This adds to the answerer's reputation and also marks this question as having an answer.